Evans PDE, Proof of Theorem $7.1.2$
I am reading the proof of the Evans's PDE, proof of Theorem $7.1.2 ( p.354 )$ and stuck at understanding some statements. Can anyone who has Evans's book help?

THEOREM $2$ ( Energy estimates ). There exists a constant $C$, depending only on $U$,$T$ and the coefficients of $L$, such that
$$ \max_{0 \le t \le T}||u_m(t)||_{L^{2}(U)} + ||u_m||_{L^2(0,T; H^1_{0}(U))} + || u_m'||_{L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(U))} \le C( ||f||_{L^{2}(0,T;L^2(U))}+||g||_{L^{2}(U)}) \tag{20}$$
for $m=1,2,\dots$ .

Proof. Steps $1,2,3$ are omitted.
Step 4. Fix any $v\in H^{1}_0(U)$, with $||v||_{H^{1}_{0}(U)}\le 1$, and write $v=v^{1}+v^{2}$, where $v^{1}\in \operatorname{span}\{{w_k}\}_{k=1}^{m}$ and $(v^2,w_k)=0$ $(k=1,\dots,m).$ Since the functions $\{ w_k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ are orthogonal in $H_{0}^{1}(U)$, $||v^{1}||_{H^{1}_{0}(U)} \le ||v||_{H^{1}_{0}(U)} \le 1 $.
Q.$1$. First question : Why this inequality is true?
EDIT : This is true by the Pythagorean theorem : since $v^1, v^2$ are orthogonal, $||v||_{H^{1}_{0}(U)}^2 = || v^1||_{H^{1}_{0}(U)}^2 + ||v^2||_{H^{1}_{0}(U)}^2 \ge || v^1||_{H^{1}_{0}(U)}^2 $. So we can move on to the next question.
( Continuing proof ) Utilizing $(16)$ , we deduce for a.e. $0 \le t \le T$ that
$$(u_m',v^1) + B[u_m,v^1;t]=(f,v^{1}). $$
Q.2. Second question : Why this equality holds for almost everywhere $0 \le t \le T$ ? It seems works. We may skip this question.
( Continuing proof ) Then $(14)$ implies
$$ \langle u'_m ,v \rangle = ( u'_m,v)=(u'_m ,v^1) = (f,v^1)-B[u_m,v^1;t]. $$
Consequently
$$ | \langle u'_m ,v \rangle | \le C ( ||f||_{L^2(U)} + ||u_m||_{H^1_0(U)}), \tag{1} $$
since $||v^1||_{H^{1}_0(U)} \le 1$.
Q.3. Third question : Why this inequality is true ? What is definition of the braket $\langle u'_m, v \rangle $ ? I think I don't know something.
EDIT : I think I made progress. My first attempt is as follows : I think that key point is the Holder's inequality and the definition of $B[u,v; t]$ ( Evans's book p.351, (8) ) .
Note that $|\langle u'_m , v \rangle | \le |(f,v^1)| + | B[u_m, v^1 ; t]|$.
First, by the Holder's inequality,
$$ |(f,v^1)| \le ||f||_2 ||v^1||_2 \le  ||f||_2 ||v^1||_{H^1_0(U)} \le ||f||_{2} \tag{2} $$
, since $||v^1||_{H^1_0(U)} \le 1$.
Second, note that ( C.f. Evans's book p.351, (8) )
$$ | B[u_m , v^1 ; t] | := | \int_U \sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a^{ij}(\cdot, t)(u_m)_{x_i}(v^1)_{x_j} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}b^{i}(\cdot, t)(u_m)_{x_i}v^1 + c(\cdot, t)u_mv^1 dx  | 
 \le \sum_{i,j =1 }^n \int_U | a^{ij}(u_m)_{x_i}(v^1)_{x_j}|dx + \sum_{i=1}^n \int_U | b^i(u_m)_{x_i}v^1|dx + \int_U|cu_mv^1|dx. \tag{3} $$
And note that ( again by the Holder's inequality )
$$ \int_U |cu_m v^1|dx \le ||c||_{L^{\infty}(U)} ||u_m v^1||_{L^{1}(U)} \le ||c||_{L^{\infty}(U)} ||u_m||_{L^{2}(U)}||v^1||_{L^2(U)} \le ||c||_{L^{\infty}(U)}||u_m||_{H^1_0(U)} ||v^1||_{H^1_0(U)} \le  ||c||_{L^{\infty}(U)}||u_m||_{H^1_0(U)}.$$
Similarly,
$$  \int_U | a^{ij}(u_m)_{x_i}(v^1)_{x_j}|dx \le || a^{ij}||_{L^{\infty}}||u_m||_{H^1_0(U)}$$
and
$$ \int_U | b^i (u_m)_{x_i}v^1|dx \le ||b^i||_{L^{\infty}(U)}||u_m||_{H^1_0(U)}.$$
Putting this all together, we get
$$ (3) \le ( \sum_{i,j-1}^n ||a^{ij}||_{L^{\infty}(U)} + \sum_{i=1}^n ||b^i||_{L^{\infty}(U)} + ||c||_{L^{\infty}(U)} ) ||u_m||_{H^{1}_0(U)}. $$
Now, combining this inequality and $(2)$, we get estimate $(1)$ above.
Correct?
( Continuing proof ) Thus
$$ || u'_m ||_{H^{-1}(U)} \le C ( ||f||_{L^2(U)} + || u_m||_{H^{1}_{0}(U)}),$$
and therefore
$$ \int_{0}^{T} || u'_m ||^2_{H^{-1}(U)} dt \le C \int_{0}^{T}||f||^2_{L^2(U)} + ||u_m||^2_{H^1_0(U)}dt \le C(||g||^2_{L^2(U)} + ||f||^2_{L^2(0,T ; L^2(U))}).$$ QED.
Can anyone help ?

$v^1$ and $v^2$ are orthogonal; maybe duality bracket?

@psl2Z :  O.K. I edit my post. And how about the third question? ( And the second question also can be answered? )
